# Remove ActionBar icon API < 11

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar, title

I'm developing an application that should be compatible with APIs from 8 above.
For versions of API>=11 I display some text in the ActionBar title, and for API<11 the text is shown in the TitleBar. This is handled by Android automatically.

If the API is 11 or above, I would like to get rid of the ActionBar icon to get some more space for the text. However, Eclipse won't let me call `getActionBar()` saying that my minimum API (8) is too low.

How can I bypass that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap all your ActionBar calls in:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  // call something for API Level 11+
}
```

The error you are getting is likely a Lint warning, and you should be able to go into the preference and reduce its level to a warning, so that your code still compiles.

Additionally, you could look into using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to get an ActionBar on devices lower than API 11.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! I will accept this as the right answer in a few minutes (StackOverflow limitations...)

Answer (score 2):

You can check your android version by

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) 
 {
      //your code
 }
```

But I'd actually advice you to use this [android support package](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) by google itself to support features on lower versions. Check it out

Comment: Thanks, I actually have this v4 support library in my project. But can I use to support ActionBar on devices with API < 11? I thought only ActionBarSherlock makes it possible.

Comment: @SzymonPrzedwojski Sorry. My bad. But google advices as *The ActionBar is not supported by the library. However, when creating your Options Menu, you can declare which items should be added to the Action Bar when it's available (on Android 3.0 or later). You can do so with the MenuCompat.setShowAsAction() method* This is how they handle ActionBar in google apps